# Arduino and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, arduino

My arduino is giving output according to this program - part of which is

```
Serial.print("A");
Serial.print(sensorValue);
Serial.print("B");
Serial.println();
Serial.print("C");
Serial.print(sensorValue1);
Serial.print("D");
Serial.println();
```

The output of which in the serial monitor of the arduino is shown as 
C491D
A192B
C49D
A192B
C484D
A196B
C482D
A193B
C483D
A199B
C485D
A196B
C486D
A198B

Now my Node.js running the following code

```
var cleanData = ""; // this stores the clean data
var cleanData1 = "";
var readData = "";  // this stores the buffer
sp.on("data", function (data) { // call back when data is received
readData += data.toString(); // append data to buffer
// console.log(readData);
// if the letters "A" and "B" are found on the buffer then isolate what"s in the middle
// as clean data. Then clear the buffer.

if (readData.indexOf("D") >= 0 && readData.indexOf("C") >= 0) {
    cleanData1 = readData.substring(readData.indexOf("C") + 1, readData.indexOf("D"));
    readData = "";
    console.log(cleanData1);
   io.sockets.emit("message", cleanData1);
}
else if(readData.indexOf("B") >= 0 && readData.indexOf("A") >= 0)
{
    cleanData = readData.substring(readData.indexOf("A") + 1, readData.indexOf("B"));
    readData = "";
    console.log(cleanData);
    io.sockets.emit("message", cleanData);
}

});
```

The console reading of the same is not giving the desired results D
A181B
C
D
A181B
C
181
462
181
462
181
462
181
462
181
462
462
462
462
462
462
462
462
462
462
462
462
462
462

From the console reading it is quite evident that the readings are not as desired . The reading should be one starting with 4 and another starting with 1. In fact there are console readings like

D
A181B
C
D
A181B
C
D
A181B
C
D
A181B
C
D
A181B
C

which should not be coming at all
If I block one If statement block , then the readings shown by any one block is perfect.

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It appears in you `data` event you are concatenating the new data but then you are checking the entire string (`readData`). So each time you check (setting cleanData) you are starting from the beginning and hitting the first result over and over.

Try chaning

```
readData += data.toString();
```

to

```
readData = data.toString();
```

This way you indexOf and substring matching will be looking at the new incoming data.

Comment: Thanks Morgan, using your method improved it a little. The output now is showing 181 181 181 462 181 462 181 462 181 462 181 462 462 462 462 462 462 462 462 . The output should be a digit between A & B (ie digit starting with 1) followed by digit between C & D (ie digit starting with 4) and then again between A & B and so on. But the output is not showing like that, it is showing five /six outputs starting with 4 , then 2/3 output starting with 1 etc. Why is this so??